# Basic mocha TDD interface

Tags: javascript, tdd, mocha.js

### Problem

I have the following file in javascript:

```
function myLocalHouse() {

this.buyHouse(money, date) {
   //code I want to test with mocha
};


};
```

I want to test the `buyHouse` method.

### What I have tried

I have tried the most easy thing in the world, but as hard as I try It doesn't work

```
var myLocalHouseInstance = require('/myLocalHouse.js');

suite('houses suite', function() {
    test('test that buy House works correctly', function() {
       var something = myLocalHouseInstance.buyHouse(100, '17/08/2013');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, when I execute `mocha` it says method `buyHouse` is undefined.

I execute the test with:

`mocha -u tdd`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your function in myLocalHouse.js. Try something like this:

```
exports.myLocalHouse = function() {
    this.buyHouse = function(money, date) {
    }
}
```

or

```
function myLocalHouse() {
    this.buyHouse = function(money, date) {
    }
}

exports.myLocalHouse = myLocalHouse;
```

then in your test

```
var myLocalHouse = require('./myLocalHouse.js').myLocalHouse;

suite('houses suite', function() {
    test('test that buy House works correctly', function() {
        var myLocalHouseInstance = new myLocalHouse();
        var something = myLocalHouseInstance.buyHouse(100, '17/08/2013');
    });
});
```